# Do charm bonuses ever max out?

Tags: diablo-ii

How many charms can I carry at once, and if I can fill my inventory, do the charm benefits reach a limit after carrying a certain amount? If not, can I theoretically fill my inventory with Annihilus charms?

Comment: why is this getting downvotes?

Comment: @Ender not sure. We can think in some points: It's a weak question. The example about Annihilus Charms was a bad one (he is unique after all). If you play D2 you know that each charm count (unless they are unique). I didn't down-vote, but not going to up-vote too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Annihilus charm is a [Unique charm](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Unique_Charms), so no, you can't fill your inventory with those, since you can only carry one of each at any time. Other than that, for the other charms there's no limit other than your inventory capacity. That's why charms are considered very valuable items: in a limited space they give you powerful bonuses.

Some links with confirmations of the stacking properties:

[DiabloWiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Charm_Affixes#Magic_Prefixes_3)
[A Gamespot forum discussion](http://www.gamespot.com/diablo-ii-lord-of-destruction/forum/do-damage-charms-stack-43083907/)
[An IncGamers forum discussion](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?649202-Quick-charm-question)

Regarding the limits, you get a cap only for skills that have a cap (for example elemental resistances are maxed out at 100%); others, such as [Magic find](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Magic_Find), have no cap, so you can hoard as many MF charms you can, but they have diminishing returns; others instead, as the +skill ones, have no cap at all, so for those the sky's the limit!(or, more realistically, you backpack)

Comment: The limit is the space in your inventory. Basically  you can have as many charms (not unique) as you can carry. Note: Charms inside RC does not work.